# How do I add a featured iTunes Radio station to my stations on iOS?

Tags: itunes-radio

On iTunes for Mac I can right click a station to add it my stations. I tried a long press on a featured station on iOS but that doesn't bring up any options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According an [Apple support doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5848):

> You can add a featured station to My Stations by tapping the Info (i)
>   button, then tapping the Plus (+) button to the right of "Add to My
>   Stations."